# How to mock the dependency of an imported class in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a dependency of a class I'm importing (note that I'm not trying to mock the imported class!), but I do not how to do it.

Example:

```js
// DependencyIWantToMock.js
class DependencyIWantToMock {
  run = async () => {};
}

// ClassIAmTesting.js
class ClassIAmTesting {
  run = async () => {
    const dependency = new DependencyIWantToMock();
    dependency.run();
  };
}

// ClassIAmTesting.test.js
import DependencyIWantToMock from './DependencyIWantToMock.js'
jest.mock('./ClassIAmTesting.js')
import ClassIAmTesting from './ClassIAmTesting.js'

test('', async () => {
  const instance = new ClassIAmTesting();
  await instance.run(); // error -> run is not a funcion (from DependencyIWantToMock)
});
```

I have been seaerching across the internet but I only find how to mock the imported class, not a dependency of the imported class.

**Note:** I know, dependency injection, I cannot use that in this case.

Any idea how to get this?

Comment: I didn't see the `DependencyIWantToMock` class being used. You are trying to test `ClassIAmTesting`, so you shouldn't mock it.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the code using the dependency. I have updated the code example.